# BODMAS Rule ("Of" vs "Division")?

Tags: education

What if the precedence of "**of**" in an expression ?

Consider this expression :-

(2/3) of (4/5) / (6/5) <== so first division will happen first of "of" will be applied ?

Comment: Bodmas is designed to be limited to math notation. So you have to convert "of" into "(2/3) * (4/5)", then apply bodmas

Comment: It doesn't matter since $(ab)/c = a(b/c)$. However, when someone writes "$\frac 1 2$ of $2+2$" I'd read that as $\frac 1 2 (2+2)$ since I'd tread $\frac 1 2$ and $2+2$ as mathematical formulas embedded into the textual expression "… of …". Now when someone writes "$\frac 1 2$ of $2$ plus $2$" I'd be lost.

Comment: "Of" just means "times", right? So replace "of" with $\times$ and then use BODMAS.

Comment: "Of" also may mean "divide": $12$ *of* $24$ punks have green hair, that's $12/24$.

Answer (score 0):

It will be $\frac{2}{3}$ of $(\frac{\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{6}{5}})$

$$\frac{2}{3}\times (\frac{\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{6}{5}})$$

Comment: Where if "of" in BODMAS rule ? is "O" mean  (Orders, powes, sqrt, and "of") ? so before division ?